# How do I add an external floppy drive to an openMSX emulated MSX 1 machine?

Tags: msx

I'd like to add an emulated floppy drive to the openMSX emulation of a fairly basic MSX 1 computer, such as the `Canon_V-8`, `Sony_HB-55P` or `National_CF-2700`. (I own all three of these, albeit an HB-55 instead of an HB-55P, and I've used my Toshiba drive kit on at least one of them, so I know that this works with real hardware.)

However, when I run `openMSX -machine … -diska .` for any of those three machines (all of which have their ROM files available), openMSX complains, `Fatal error: No disk drive A present to put image '.' in.` (The `-diska` option seems to work fine with MSX 1 machines that have a built-in drive, such as the `National_CF-3300`, which uses the same BASIC/BIOS ROM as the CF-2700 but has an additional disk ROM.)

I'm guessing that I am just missing some configuration here, but the [openMSX Setup Guide](https://openmsx.org/manual/setup.html) doesn't seem to provide any hints on what to do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most MSX1 machines do not have the required floppy drive interfacing capabilities built-in. Notably, the needed system software, the so-called [Disk ROM](https://www.msx.org/wiki/Disk_ROM) is missing from MSX1 machines without a floppy drive.

If you want to use floppy disks with a machine that doesn't have that built in, you have to do what you would do with a real MSX1 machine: connect an external floppy drive interface cartridge, such as the [Sony HBD-F1](https://www.msx.org/wiki/Sony_HBD-F1). Well, it's actually a complete interface+drive combo.

Use the `-ext` parameter to specify the cartridge model, e.g.

```
openmsx -machine Spectravideo_SVI-728 -ext Sony_HBD-F1 -diska disk-image.dsk
```

With the floppy drive added to the machine, the `-diska` parameter works. The `-diska` parameter has to come after the `-ext` parameter.

The cartridge you "insert" contains, among other things, the Disk ROM, and your MSX gets new software with it. When starting the machine with the floppy drive, but no bootable disk in the drive, it should boot to BASIC and show you a new text "Disk BASIC version 1.0" and the amount of free memory is smaller than before. It will also ask for the current date, "Enter date (M-D-Y)".

[image: MSX Disk BASIC]

The MSX.org wiki page about Disk ROM claims that Disk BASIC requires 32 kB RAM, but I was able to get the Sony HBD-F1 to work with an emulated National CF-1200 machine which only has 16k. BASIC reported "7047 Bytes free", and I could save and load BASIC programs without problems. I do have a real HBD-F1, but no real 16k RAM machines to test this, but I assume it would work on a real machine as well.

Comment: It may be worth adding a note that the parameters are order-sensitive; the `-diska` parameter must come _after_ the `-ext` parameter that adds the floppy drive.

Comment: So openMSX is the equivalent of that guy you knew at university, who made you ashamed to have any connection whatsoever to computer science: “I want to emulate an MSX and a disk drive, please”; “Sure”; “Why doesn’t this MSX act like it has a disk drive?”; “You never said the two had to be connected! Tee hee.”

Comment: @Tommy If you're saying that openMSX doesn't have great documentation, yeah, in some areas it can be a bit of work to figure out the answers to questions like this. That's sort of situation is exactly why we have StackExchange sites.

Comment: @piiperi Thanks for the edit with all that excellent extra information! I'd give you another upvote if I could.

Comment: @cjs I'm saying it's user-hostile for software silently to accept a nonsensical configuration. Especially here where there's absolutely no ambiguity in the user's intent when asking for a disk image to be used with a machine, meaning that the configuration could very trivially be made correct.

Comment: @Tommy I think this just reflects the general way of thinking in the MSX hobbyist community. You cannot trivially assume any specific expansions, because there are so many possible configurations. Who knows, maybe some drive interface doesn't work with some 16K machine model? What if your software requires more RAM or MSX2 VDP and a specific sound expansion, should the emulator try to detect the software and automagically change the configuration according to some online database of "known good configs for this software"? Or should it do what the asked-for setup would actually do?

Comment: @Tommy openMSX does _not_ "silently accept a nonsensical configuration." If you ask to insert a diskette into a machine without a drive attached, it correctly says, "I can't do that," refuses to start, and then, reasonably enough, leaves it to the user to decide whether to modify her command line to attach a drive or remove the diskette. The issue here is merely documentation: the obvious starter document doesn't make it obvious how to add a drive to a configuration for a machine without a built-in drive.

Comment: @cjs on your second, agreed — I had misread your post, somehow inventing within the fiction of my mind that the emulator was starting without paying heed to the disk image. So that's me being a nonsense man.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica if you're actually asking, then my answer is that the emulator should detect and change configurations. There's some subset of the community that wants to emulate a specific configuration, then there's some other subset that just wants to run the software. I think that if a user hasn't identified themselves as being in the former group by being specific, it is valid to assume they're in the latter.

Comment: @Tommy Are you talking about the MSX hobbyist community and OpenMSX command line users specifically? My experience is that MSX hobbyists are interested in expansions, device capabilities and history. OpenMSX is made for that group of people, to reproduce the exact behavior of specific configurations. Command line users are a narrower subset of all users.

Comment: @Tommy I disagree that the emulator should pick an arbitrary configuration for the user that's different from what he asked for. If my error was in using the `-diska` option (i.e., my intent was _not_ to use it, but I accidentally did), changing my configuration to somehow hopefully make that work (assuming it picked the correct drive for my purposes!) would go off into an unintended configuration and make the problem harder to debug. Programs, when they encounter a problem, should clearly state the problem, not try to hide it. (I learned this from decades of debugging problems.)

Comment: @Tommy As far as "the subset [of users] that just want to run the software," this isn't generally an issue for them because they're selecting MSX2 machines with built-in drives. (As they should be; these will run the broadest range of MSX software, including all MSX1 software.) I was deliberately aiming for a more unusual configuration that was designed _not_ to be able to run certain types of software.

Comment: @cjs Yeah, we're clearly talking about very different things. Again, I'm talking about users who have a piece of software, and want to run that piece of software. If they're taking the time to select a specific machine, that's a different use case.